# could not connect to the debugger cocoa app Visual Studio MAC

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, cocoa, visual-studio-mac

Hello i am new in Visual Studio MAC, i developed many application on Windows using Visual studio but i started on macOS recently.
I am developing an application in COCOA APP using Xamarin on Visual Studio MAC, i just created application by selecting COCOA App but it won't start and having prompt saying 'could not connect to the debugger' but build successful.

Things i tried
Changing compile target, tried executable, executable with GUI
Changing linker behaviour, SDKs only and Link all

I didn't find any other solutions on searching please help me out i am adding application output below.

```
Runtime critical type System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData not found

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Adddress Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x7fff74a15b66):0x7fff74a15b56  ff ff c3 90 90 90 b8 48 01 00 02 49 89 ca 0f 05  .......H...I....
0x7fff74a15b66  73 08 48 89 c7 e9 75 6f ff ff c3 90 90 90 b8 4c  s.H...uo.......L
0x7fff74a15b76  01 00 02 49 89 ca 0f 05 73 08 48 89 c7 e9 5d 6f  ...I....s.H...]o
0x7fff74a15b86  ff ff c3 90 90 90 b8 49 01 00 02 49 89 ca 0f 05  .......I...I....

=====================
Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
    External Debugger Dump:
=================================================================
============================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x1029fd078 - /Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MacOS/abcproj : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x1029f0c15 - /Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MacOS/abcproj : mono_handle_native_crash
    0x7fff74bd3f5a - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
    0x1118eb768 - Unknown
    0x7fff749711ae - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib : abort
    0x102c22577 - /Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MacOS/abcproj : monoeg_assert_abort
    0x102c077bf - /Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MacOS/abcproj : mono_log_write_logfile
    0x102c228fe - /Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MacOS/abcproj : monoeg_g_logv_nofree
    0x102c229b2 - /Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MacOS/abcproj : monoeg_g_log
    0x102aa44a5 - /Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MacOS/abcproj : mono_class_load_from_name
    0x102ac14dc - /Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MacOS/abcproj : mono_init_internal
    0x102a05326 - /Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MacOS/abcproj : mini_init
    0x10295ee63 - /Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MacOS/abcproj : mono_main
    0x10291b2bc - /Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MacOS/abcproj : xamarin_main
    0x10291c0e4 - /Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MacOS/abcproj : main
    0x7fff748c5015 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : start
    0x2 - Unknown

=================================================================
    Telemetry Dumper:
=================================================================
(lldb) command source -s 0 '/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.8523'
Executing commands in '/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.8523'.
(lldb) process attach --pid 8523
Process 8523 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'tid_307', queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fff74a1622a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4:
->  0x7fff74a1622a <+10>: jae    0x7fff74a16234            ; <+20>
    0x7fff74a1622c <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff74a1622f <+15>: jmp    0x7fff74a0cb0a            ; cerror
    0x7fff74a16234 <+20>: retq   
Target 0: (abcproj) stopped.

Executable module set to "/Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MacOS/abcproj".
Architecture set to: x86_64-apple-macosx.
(lldb) thread list
Process 8523 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x5ca84, 0x00007fff74a1622a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10, name = 'tid_307', queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  thread #2: tid = 0x5ca9b, 0x00007fff74a1628a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
  thread #3: tid = 0x5ca9c, 0x00007fff74a1628a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
  thread #4: tid = 0x5caa1, 0x00007fff74a15a16 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10, name = 'SGen worker'
(lldb) thread backtrace all
* thread #1, name = 'tid_307', queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff74a1622a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10
    frame #1: 0x00000001029fd2d0 abcproj`mono_dump_native_crash_info at mini-posix.c:1112 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x00000001029fd014 abcproj`mono_dump_native_crash_info(signal=<unavailable>, ctx=<unavailable>, info=<unavailable>) at mini-posix.c:1149 [opt]
    frame #3: 0x00000001029f0c15 abcproj`mono_handle_native_crash(signal="SIGABRT", ctx=0x00007ffeed2f4940, info=0x00007ffeed2f48d8) at mini-exceptions.c:3290 [opt]
    frame #4: 0x00007fff74bd3f5a libsystem_platform.dylib`_sigtramp + 26
    frame #5: 0x00007fff74a15b67 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 11
    frame #6: 0x00007fff74be0080 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 333
    frame #7: 0x00007fff749711ae libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #8: 0x0000000102c22577 abcproj`monoeg_assert_abort at goutput.c:57 [opt]
    frame #9: 0x0000000102c077bf abcproj`mono_log_write_logfile(log_domain=<unavailable>, level=<unavailable>, hdr=<unavailable>, message="Runtime critical type System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData not found") at mono-log-common.c:135 [opt]
    frame #10: 0x0000000102c228fe abcproj`monoeg_g_logv_nofree [inlined] monoeg_g_logstr(log_domain=0x0000000000000000, log_level=G_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, msg=<unavailable>) at goutput.c:134 [opt]
    frame #11: 0x0000000102c228d5 abcproj`monoeg_g_logv_nofree(log_domain=0x0000000000000000, log_level=G_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, format="Runtime critical type %s.%s not found", args=<unavailable>) at goutput.c:149 [opt]
    frame #12: 0x0000000102c229b2 abcproj`monoeg_g_log [inlined] monoeg_g_logv(log_domain=<unavailable>, log_level=<unavailable>, format=<unavailable>, args=<unavailable>) at goutput.c:156 [opt]
    frame #13: 0x0000000102c229ad abcproj`monoeg_g_log(log_domain=<unavailable>, log_level=<unavailable>, format=<unavailable>) at goutput.c:165 [opt]
    frame #14: 0x0000000102aa44a5 abcproj`mono_class_load_from_name(image=<unavailable>, name_space="System.Reflection", name="CustomAttributeData") at class.c:3157 [opt]
    frame #15: 0x0000000102ac14dc abcproj`mono_init_internal(filename=<unavailable>, exe_filename=<unavailable>, runtime_version=<unavailable>) at domain.c:764 [opt]
    frame #16: 0x0000000102a05326 abcproj`mini_init(filename="/Users/macbookpro/Projects/abcproj/abcproj/bin/Debug/abcproj.app/Contents/MonoBundle/abcproj.exe", runtime_version="mobile") at mini-runtime.c:4426 [opt]
    frame #17: 0x000000010295ee63 abcproj`mono_main(argc=6, argv=0x0000604000068180) at driver.g.c:2324 [opt]
    frame #18: 0x000000010291b2bc abcproj`::xamarin_main(argc=2, argv=0x00007ffeed2f5650, launch_mode=XamarinLaunchModeApp) at launcher.m:647
    frame #19: 0x000000010291c0e4 abcproj`main(argc=2, argv=0x00007ffeed2f5650) at launcher.m:666
    frame #20: 0x00007fff748c5015 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
  thread #2
    frame #0: 0x00007fff74a1628a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff74bdd009 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1035
    frame #2: 0x00007fff74bdcbe9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
  thread #3
    frame #0: 0x00007fff74a1628a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff74bdd20e libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1552
    frame #2: 0x00007fff74bdcbe9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
  thread #4, name = 'SGen worker'
    frame #0: 0x00007fff74a15a16 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff74bde589 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 732
    frame #2: 0x0000000102bf878e abcproj`thread_func [inlined] mono_os_cond_wait(mutex=<unavailable>) at mono-os-mutex.h:173 [opt]
    frame #3: 0x0000000102bf877b abcproj`thread_func at sgen-thread-pool.c:165 [opt]
    frame #4: 0x0000000102bf876d abcproj`thread_func(data=0x0000000000000000) at sgen-thread-pool.c:196 [opt]
    frame #5: 0x00007fff74bdd661 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 340
    frame #6: 0x00007fff74bdd50d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 377
    frame #7: 0x00007fff74bdcbf9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
(lldb) detach
(lldb) quit
```

Comment: Hi, do you have a check with the [Required Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/#required-components) in the Mac?

Comment: yes @JuniorJiang